Is there more to imbalanced classification with XGBoost than simply reweighting the loss function?
I am working on a dataset for fraud detection, which is naturally heavily imbalanced. My classifier is a class weighted XGBoost. In other words, I simply overweight the positive class by tweaking XGBoost's scale_pos_weight parameter.
However, a quick glance at the literature reveals a plethora of techniques for dealing with imbalanced datasets. It makes me wonder whether one should expect more advanced methods like Tomek links, ADASYN, etc. to yield substantially better performance than my basic fiddling with the loss function. But at the same time, I cannot think of the intuition for why they would given that they don't create "more data" out of the data, so to speak. Do you have any insight on this?

Are you sure the imbalance is a problem? Statistics says it probably isn’t.

As the comment states, dataset imbalance may not be a problem, per se. You could try implementing the XGBoost model without reweighting/resampling, versus doing reweighting/resampling, and see whether there are differences in model performance.
However, if you really do want to do resampling, you could try random oversampling, SMOTE, SMOTE-ENN, SMOTE-Tomek Links, etc. This may or may not help your model performance, whatever you attribute that to be. These resampling techniques could be "better" than reweighting, but you would also have to test it out.
